# How to enable EditText to take input Special Characters like ~!#$%^&*()_-{[}]? and others with app:endIconMode="password_toggle" Enabled in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-edittext

I am using app:endIconMode="password_toggle"  in EditText TextInputLayout to toggle password visibility and want all special characters like "~!@#$%^&*()_-{[}]?" to accept by EditText in this scenario I am not able to type above characters like ~,!,{,},[,] etc.

How am i suppose to acquire my requirement ? any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use inputType textEmailAddress or textPassword to accept all characters.

android:inputType="textPassword"